# properties of solution

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I had homework with the following question, Eugenol is the active ingredient in the oil of cloves used to relieve toothache. Calculate the boiling point of a solution in which 0.17 grams of eugenol, (C10H12, O2) is dissolved in 10.0 grams of benzene. (Kb benzene= 2.53 0C/m; Tb(solvent) = 80.100C). Show your solution.

I solved it like this but it's wrong, I would like to know your thoughts.
[image]

Comment: @Martin Hmm, I think closing this Q as duplicate without clarification, when a newcomer tries to improve the closed question erroneously in a new post, may left the OP very confused.

Comment: Tried rather to edit the original question, the best if you write your solution attempt as text,  instead of picture, and then ask for its reopening.

Comment: @Poutnik It _is_ the same question, from a moderational point of view there is only one more option: deletion. And that is harsher, I guess.

Comment: @Martin I do agree it is the same question to be closed as duplicate. :-) I have meant  there is always an option to post a short comment.

Comment: @Poutnik I have not much time to enjoy this site, so I chose to handle this quickly and without further comment. I did this because I saw that you have posted a well meaning comment on the original question. I believe all the information about the site is easily accessible before you hit the post button, so I do not think special care is necessary after the fact that the poster has ignored most of the warnings. There is unfortunately more that I need to get to, so excuse my brevity.